# What is wrong with this particular iptables command?

Tags: iptables, router, netfilter

On an older router, I was using this command:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i br0 -s 192.168.157.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 7
```

That router died (red led of death), and now I'm forced to try to recreate an implementation I didn't quite understand even when I got it working the first time. Anyway, the error message it produces is so:

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

If I leave everything off of if after -j, then this command will execute successfully (though does little to accomplish my goals). That suggests to me that both PREROUTING and mangle are available. I remember vaguely that packet marking might be its own kernel module, but I'm not even able to determine what its name would be, were that the case.

What do I need to do to debug this? I'm not sure where to start with this one. Is something not compiled into the kernel that should be?

The kernel version appears to be 2.6.22.19.

I have other iptables commands that are failing similarly, though I expect that the explanation for this one command will shed light on the others.

Comment: 2.6.22? You should probably update your kernel to something recent.... You'll want to use xt_mark/xt_connmark, are they loaded? What does dmesg say?

Comment: This is a router, I'd have to set up a cross-compile environment... not competent to do that myself. Neither of those look to be loaded from lsmod (though nf_conntrack_* modules are). Dmesg shows nothing interesting, just interfaces going into prom mode from where I've been using tcpdump.

Comment: Hmm, can you try to load the modules manually? Some of the netfilter modules were renamed at some point, but I think 2.6.22 should already call them xt_mark and xt_connmark...